# How can i Add character from char

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, char

How can I add additional 30 character from the char that matches where in my code below.

```
private void CheckGarbageCharacters(string input)
{
    var contentList = File.ReadAllLines(input).ToList();
    int[] lineno = { 0 };
    foreach (var line in contentList)
    {
        lineno[0]++;
        foreach (var errorModel in from c in line
                                   where c > '\u007F'
                                   select new ErrorModel
                                   {
                                       Filename = Path.GetFileName(input),
                                       LineNumber = lineno[0],
                                       ErrorMessage = "Garbage character found.",
                                       Text = c.ToString()
                                   })

        {
            _errorList.Add(errorModel);
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: In Text = c.ToString(), I want to add some text after c which is beside c, because c.Tostring() matches only 1 character, I want to add 30 character after c.Tostring()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but based on the code you have provided it seems like you are trying to do something like this...

~ Pseudo Code ~ This has not been tested ~

```
private void CheckGarbageCharacters(string filename)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename).ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
    {
         var line = lines[i];
         for (int j = 0; j < line.Length; j++)
         {
              var c = line[j];
              if (c > '\u007F')
              {
                   // Grab the next 30 characters after 'c'
                   var text = c.ToString();
                   for (int k = 0; k < 30; k++)
                   {
                        if ((j + k) > (line.Length - 1))
                        {
                             break;
                        }
                        text += line[j + k].ToString();
                   }
                   // Create the error message
                   var error = new ErrorModel()
                   {
                        Filename = Path.GetFileName(filename),
                        LineNumber = i,
                        ErrorMessage = "Garbage character found.",
                        Text = text
                   };
                   // Add the error to the list
                   _errorList.Add(error);
              }
         }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "add additional 30 characters from the char that matches where in my code" though.

**EDIT**

I've updated my answer according to the information you've provided in the comments. I believe this is what you are trying to do here.

Comment: In Text = c.ToString(), I want to add some text after c which is beside c, because c.Tostring() matches only 1 character, I want to add 30 character after c.Tostring()

Comment: @ErwinAlcantara You should then use something like `Text = line.Substring(j, Math.Min(30, line.Length - j))`. Note that this will not include characters from the following line.

Comment: Since I cannot make 1 character edits I'll point out that you're missing the `u` character in the character literal (it should read `'\u007F'`).